# How to move account from Garena?

Tags: league-of-legends

I play League of Legends on a daily basis in a client that is available in the South East Asian region called "GARENA", which is the official publisher of LoL in Taiwan, Singapore, Malaysia, etc.

My question is, how do I move the account from there to the normal League of Legends client, if at all possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just in case people get close-vote-trigger-happy: Garena is the official publisher of LoL in SEA and Taiwan.

Comment: @MrLemon Yes. Thank you for clearing that up. i will edit my post now to clarify that.

Comment: "Normal League of Legends" = ones owned and maintained by Riot Games?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see, the last time Garena offered transfers to any Riot server is [3 years ago, when they used to offer transfers to the Oceania server.](http://oce.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/features/free-transfers-garena-oceania-now-available) The offer ended by the end of 2013.

Since then, I haven't seen *any* request for a Garena-to-Riot transfer entertained within any of their public support channels. Quoting a [post](http://forum.lol.garena.ph/showthread.php?128100-Can-I-transfer-my-Garena-LoL-to-another-foreign-server-for-example-NA&p=1458424&viewfull=1#post1458424) from player support for the Philippines server,

> Hi, unfortunately account transfer/migration to other server is
>   already not possible. You would need to start a new account if you
>   want to play on other LoL regions.

Comment: awww man. what a bummer

Answer (score 1):

The best case is to contact [support](http://support.lol.garena.com/en_SG) , I've done some looking and a page they had called "[Transfer](http://lol.garena.com/transfer)" is no longer available, so it seems the only way to transfer, if it's even possible, is to contact support and request a transfer. They may be able to do something. Failing that, it seems making a new account might be the only solution to play on a different region.